# Validar si un vector está dentro de otro

Tags: python

Este código de Python debe decidir si un vector está dentro de otro.

```
def Incluir(U,V):
    m =  len(U)
    n = len(V)
    i = 1
    for j in range (len(V)):
        print("s")
        if (U[0] == V[j]):

            k = j+1
            cont = 0
            while (U[i] == V [k]):
                print("*")
                k = k+1
                i = i+1
            r = i
            print("r =" ,+ r)

    if (r == len(U)):

        return (1)
    else:
        return (-1)

U = [1,2,3]
V = [1,0, 3, 1,2,3,0]
print(Incluir(U,V))
```

Sin embargo, no funciona. ¿Por qué?

Comment: por favor, indica qué es lo que falla. Siempre es bueno proveer un [mcve]

Comment: Estaría genial que pusieras varios ejemplos con la respuesta esperada para saber qué devolver en cada caso. ¿Importa el orden de aparición de los elementos? Si el orden importa, ¿podría haber elementos intercalados? Estaría bien saber para qué se va a utilizar esta función... :)

Answer (score 2):

Hay algunas consideraciones con **Python** que pueden allanar lo solicitado.

Si se tiene `lista=[10,20,30]`, **Python** es capaz de iterarla en un bucle `for` de dos formas de acuerdo a nuestras necesidades.

```
for i in range(len(lista)): print(lista[i]) #10 20 30
for val in lista: print(val) #10 20 30
```

Las dos son correctas, todo depende de que se quiera lograr, a veces es necesario trabajar con los indices o un rango parcial de la lista, en dicho caso es válido decantarse por la primera opción.

La segunda opción en cambio devuelve el valor **"en"** (`in`) lista, para este caso, como se pide verificar si un vector esta incluido **"en"** otro vector, se puede tomar lo siguiente también:

```
print(3 in [1,2,3]) # TRUE
```

Entonces para efectos de allanar un poco la explicación, voy a asumir que `v` es mayor o igual que `u` por un momento:

```
v = [2,4,5,4,1,3]
u = [1,2,3,5,6]
```

Por tanto verbalizando lo que se le va ha preguntar a **Python**:

> ¿Está **"cada"** elemento de `u` **"en"** `v`?

```
resp=[elementoU in v for elemementoU in u]
print(resp)
#[True, True, True, True, False]
```

En este caso se obtiene una lista `booleana`. Entonces de igual forma se pregunta con el método `all` si todos son verdaderos

```
all([True, True, True, True, False]) # False
```

Para ir terminado, ¿qué sucede cuando `len(v)<len(u)`? en dicho caso, sólo se realiza un cambio de variable: `u, v = v, u`

En tal sentido, el código quedaría así

```
def Incluir(u,v): 
    if len(v)<len(u): u, v = v, u
    return all([i in v for i in u])
```

Probando el código

```
u = [2,4,5,4,1,3]
v = [1,2,3,5,6]
print(Incluir(v,u)) # puse al reves para que se aprecie el cambio de variable
# False

print(Incluir([1,2,3],[2,1,3])) 
# True
```

Comment: Menuda voltereta hacia atrás con el `in for in`, mi enhorabuena por la respuesta. ¿Dónde se puede aprender más sobre eso? ¿Algún enlace que nos puedas recomendar? :)

Comment: Hola @David qué tal, para ser honesto contigo me encuentro en un proceso de migración de **Lua** a **Python**, y como son lenguajes parecidos (Incluso entre **Lua** y **Javascript**) trato (cuando se puede) extrapolar los conceptos de programación de mi lenguaje paterno **Lua** (materno fue **matlab**) a otros. Algo similar debe pasarle a vos con **SQL** :) **mysql, sqlite, postgresql,...**, no obstante, hay una página [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python!](https://docs.python-guide.org/) que puede ser útil, a parte claro de `google dot com`

Comment: Hola @HubertRonald, parece que el enunciado de la pregunta no estaba del todo completo y faltaban casos particulares por describir :( Con mi algoritmo artesano he podido adaptarme, con el tuyo no me atrevo... :)

Comment: Hola @David qué tal!, viendo el comentario del **OP**, aplicando la función que expuse con los vectores `U = [1,2,3] V = [1,0,4,1,2,3]` se obtiene `True` *-es decir `U` sí está incluido en `V`-*. Adicionalmente, aunque quisiera con el mayor de los gustos incluir variantes o ampliar mi respuesta, como la pregunta ha sido puesta en espera, ya depende del **OP** hacer los cambios respectivos a su pregunta para revertir dicha situación, a fin de que la comunidad pueda ayudarle mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te has liado con los índices de los vectores (el error que da ese código es de exceder sus dimensiones), no lo sé, me he perdido un poco con tantos contadores. Intuyo que querías hacer algo así:

```
def Incluir(U,V):
    m = len(U)
    n = len(V)
    r = 0
    resultado = 0
    if(n>m):
        for j in range(n):
            if (U[0] == V[j]):
                if(n-j>=m):
                    for i in range(m):
                        if(U[i]==V[j+i]):
                            r+=1
                if (r == m):
                    resultado+=1
            else:
                r = 0
    return resultado

U = [1,2,3]
V = [1,0,4,1,2,3,5]
print(Incluir(U,V))
```

Ahora la función `Incluir` te devolverá el número de veces que aparece un vector en otro. Ojo: debe aparecer completo, sin elementos en medio y en el mismo orden.

Comment: Gracias David, eso es lo que quería hacer, el problema reside ahora en que si tomo dos vectores como los siguientes: U = [1,2,3]
V = [1,0,4,1,2,3] el programa no puede decidir si U esta dentro de V, te agradecería si puede ayudarme, igual gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Ok, modifico la respuesta para que se adapte a tus especificaciones. Modifica tu pregunta añadiendo este ejemplo para que no sea necesario localizar la información entre los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias David, me fue de mucha utilidad esta entrada, una pregunta más si en caso fuera una matriz dentro de otra matriz. voy a modificar mi pregunta para que se adapte al nuevo ejemplo.